# Creating Flow Diagram Using Matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, flow-charts

I am creating a flow diagram using Matrix, and I have inner layer that I want to connect the arrows from. How can I achieve the following:

[image]

I am also trying to separate the heading into a node (illustrated below) so that matrix dont grow thick as the headings for each matrix increases. The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,matrix}

\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1cm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
            topology/.style={rounded corners,
                           draw=white!50,
                           fill=white!20,
                           thick,
                           inner sep=3pt},
            neuron/.style={fill=black!10,
                           draw=black,
                           rounded corners,
                           inner sep=15pt},
            synapse/.style={draw=black!50,
                           fill=black,
                           rounded corners,
                           inner sep=5pt},
            empty synapse/.style={draw=none,
                           fill=none,
                           rounded corners,
                           inner sep=5pt}
}
\colorlet{colIP}{white!40}

\pgfdeclarelayer{topology}
\pgfsetlayers{topology,main}
\definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{7.36, 0.54, 0.66}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]

\matrix (N0) [neuron,inner sep=3mm,
                     matrix of nodes,
                     nodes={synapse,draw=black},
                     row sep=1mm,
                     nodes in empty cells,
                     outer sep=2mm]{
|[label={[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0]90:Avara Ka Davara}]| \textcolor{white}{Synapse$_1$} \\
\textcolor{white}{Synapse$_2$} \\
| [empty synapse] | $\vdots$ \\
\textcolor{white}{Synapse$_n$} \\
};

\matrix (N1) at (5,0) [neuron,inner sep=3mm,
                     matrix of nodes,
                     nodes={synapse,draw=blue},
                     row sep=1mm,
                     nodes in empty cells,
                     outer sep=2mm]{
|[label={[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0]90: Expecto Patronum}]| Synapse$_1$ \\
Synapse$_2$ \\
Synapse$_3$ \\
Synapse$_4$ \\
};

\matrix (N2) at (10,0) [neuron,inner sep=3mm,
                     matrix of nodes,
                     nodes={synapse,draw=blue},
                     row sep=1mm,
                     nodes in empty cells,
                     outer sep=2mm]{
|[label={[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0]90: Wingardium Leviosa}]| Synapse$_1$ \\
Synapse$_2$ \\
Synapse$_3$ \\
Synapse$_4$ \\
};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{topology}
\node[fit=(N0)(N1),topology,xshift=2mm,yshift=-1.5mm,minimum height=8cm] (T) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable. The best in form of a MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document which we can compile as it is.

Comment: @Zarko thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the code.

Comment: But your MWE still not work ... error: undefined color `grey` etc

Comment: @Zarko I rendered the diagram with no problems somehow. I have changed the colors to black. Can you please check if its rendering fine now?

Comment: Meanwhile I wrote my answer. See if iz is what you after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I (just) guess that you like to draw the following image:

[image]

Sorry, but I was lost in your code, so most of the following MWE I wrote from scratch. At this I might misinterpret some parts of your code. Let me know, if this is what happened.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit,
                matrix,
                positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\tikzset{
   arr/.style = {-{Triangle[scale=0.8]}, 
                 draw=gray, ultra thick,
                 shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm}, 
    en/.style = {draw=none, fill=none, text=black},
every label/.append style = {font=\bfseries, text=black, inner sep=0pt},
   FIT/.style = {draw=gray, fill=gray!30, rounded corners, 
                 inner xsep=2em, inner ysep=3ex, yshift=2ex,
                 fit = #1, node contents={}},
neuron/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                 nodes={draw=blue, rounded corners, fill=gray!50, 
                        text height=2ex, minimum width=6em, 
                        inner sep=1mm,
                        text=#1},
                 row sep=2mm,
                 outer sep=2mm},
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 11mm
                        ]
%%%
\matrix (N0) [neuron=white]
{
|[label=:Avara Ka Davara]| Synapse$_1$         \\
Synapse$_2$         \\
|[en]| $\vdots$     \\
Synapse$_n$         \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node (f0) [FIT=(N0-1-1) (N0-4-1)];

\matrix (N1) [neuron=black, right=of N0]
{
|[label=Expecto Patronum]| Synapse$_1$ \\
Synapse$_2$     \\
Synapse$_3$     \\
Synapse$_4$     \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node (f1) [FIT=(N1-1-1) (N1-4-1)];

\matrix (N2) [neuron=black, right=of N1]
{
|[label=Expecto Patronum]| Synapse$_1$ \\
Synapse$_2$     \\
Synapse$_3$     \\
Synapse$_4$     \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node (f2) [FIT=(N2-1-1) (N2-4-1)];
%%%%
\draw[arr] (N0-1-1 -| f0.east) -- (N1-1-1 -| f1.west);
\draw[arr] (f1) -- (f2);
\coordinate[below left= of N0.south west] (aux);
\draw[arr] (f2.east) -- ++ (5mm,0) |- (aux) |- (f0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Your request in comment ca be fulfilled on different way, however if you expect, that solution should automatically preserve equal height of `FIT` nodes, than this become very demanding/complex problem.

Let firs show a simpler case, when `FIT` nodes can have different heights:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit,
                matrix,
                positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\tikzset{
   arr/.style = {-{Triangle[scale=0.8]}, 
                 draw=gray, ultra thick,
                 shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm}, 
    en/.style = {draw=none, fill=none, text=black},
every label/.append style = {name=LN, anchor=south,     % <---
                 font=\bfseries, text=black, 
                 text width=10em, align=flush center,   % <---
                 yshift=1ex},                           % <---
   FIT/.style = {draw=gray, fill=gray!30, rounded corners, 
                 inner sep=1ex,
                 fit=#1, node contents={}},
neuron/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                 nodes={draw=blue, rounded corners, fill=gray!50, 
                        text height=2ex, minimum width=6em, 
                        inner sep=1mm,
                        text=#1},
                 row sep=2mm,
                 outer sep=0mm},
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm and 11mm                            % <---
                        ]
%%%
\matrix (N0) [neuron=white]
{
|[label=Avara Ka Davara
        Avara Ka Davara]| Synapse$_1$         \\        % <--- longer label
Synapse$_2$         \\
|[en]| $\vdots$     \\
Synapse$_n$         \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node (f0) [FIT=(LN) (N0-4-1)];                     % <---

\matrix (N1) [neuron=black, 
              above right=of N0.south east]             % <---
{
|[label=Expecto Patronum]| Synapse$_1$ \\
Synapse$_2$     \\
Synapse$_3$     \\
Synapse$_4$     \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node (f1) [FIT=(LN) (N1-4-1)];

\matrix (N2) [neuron=black,
              above right=of N1.south east]             % <---
{
|[label=Expecto Patronumy]| Synapse$_1$ \\
Synapse$_2$     \\
Synapse$_3$     \\
Synapse$_4$     \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node (f2) [FIT=(LN) (N2-4-1)];
%%%%
\draw[arr] (N0-1-1 -| f0.east) -- (N0-1-1 -| f1.west);  % <---
\draw[arr] (f1) -- (f1 -| f2.west);                     % <---
\coordinate[below left= 0.5 and 0.5 of N0.south west] (aux);    % <---
\draw[arr] (f2.east) -- ++ (0.5,0) |- (aux) |- (f0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For solution with equal height of `FIT` nodes please ask new question because (i) it is new problem, not asked in question, (ii) it's been bedtime here for a while ...

Comment: Awsome!! +1 for having to write it from scratch. My applogies for not being able to see you additional comment. Just out of curiosity is there a way to have the headings separate so the width of the matrix dont become big if I write long headings? I illustrated it in the picture attached, the left most matrix

Comment: @user0193, it is possible. You need to define text width of label, way of aligning of it content and give a name of label, which is than considered in `FIT` node. I will wrote an addendum about this ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for that. I shall try the addendum part!

Comment: I want to ask what is `-4-1` in  `\node (f1) [FIT=(LN) (N1-4-1)];`? I thought its offset but when I do  `\node (f1) [FIT=(LN) (N1-4-2)];` it gives me error about name. But this name is not defined anywhere only  name `N1` is defined

Comment: @user0193, each node in matrix has a name. It is composed from matrix name, in your case `N1`, `N2` and `N3` and position of node in matrix. For example `N1-4-1` is `N1-<row>-<column>`. For more details please read `tikz` package documentation, *chapter 59 Matrix Library*, page 710.