# Adding Offset to Node Fitted on 2 Matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, flow-charts

I have 2 problems with the following diagram:

1. I need to decrease space only between two matrix N2 & N5
2. I need to offset the node to be slightly larger then the matrix N2 & N5 that it is spanning

[image]

I am doing `[fit={([shift={(5em,2em)}]N2-1-1) ([shift={(-5em,-2em)}]N5-4-1)}` but shifting is not working.

The minimum working example modified from @Zarko 's [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647293/creating-flow-diagram-using-matrix/647352?noredirect=1#comment1617471_647352) is follows:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
               backgrounds,
               fit,
               matrix,
               positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  arr/.style = {-{Triangle[scale=0.8]}, 
                draw=gray, ultra thick,
                shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm}, 
   en/.style = {draw=none, fill=none, text=black},
every label/.append style = {name=LN, anchor=south,     % <---
                font=\bfseries, text=black, 
                text width=10em, align=flush center,   % <---
                yshift=1ex},                           % <---
  FIT/.style = {draw=gray, fill=gray!30, rounded corners, 
                inner sep=1ex,
                fit=#1, node contents={}},
neuron/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                nodes={draw=pink, rounded corners, fill=gray!50, 
                       text height=2ex, minimum width=2em, 
                       inner sep=1mm,
                       text=#1},
                row sep=2mm,
                outer sep=0mm},
       }
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm and 1mm                            % <---
                       ]
%%%

\matrix (N2) [neuron=white,
             ]             % <---
{
|[label=Title]| a  \\
b    \\
d   \\
c     \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
   \node (f2) [FIT=(N2-1-1) (N2-4-1)];
%%%%
\matrix (N5) [neuron=white, above right=of f2.south east]
{
|[label= Title
       ]| a      \\        % <--- longer label
b        \\
d   \\
c          \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
   \node (f3) [FIT=(N5-1-1) (N5-4-1)];           
   % <---
\scoped[on background layer]
   \node (f4) [fit={([shift={(5em,2em)}]N2-1-1) ([shift={(-5em,-2em)}]N5-4-1)},draw=gray, fill=gray!30,rounded corners, ]{}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Also I tried to bring the two matrix infront of node f4 by changing `\scoped[on background layer]` to `\scoped[]` it kind of worked but then the text and the matrix was also gone!

[image]

The following is what I want but with the space between the two specific matrix less then (other matrix)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
               backgrounds,
               fit,
               matrix,
               positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  arr/.style = {-{Triangle[scale=0.8]}, 
                draw=gray, ultra thick,
                shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm}, 
   en/.style = {draw=none, fill=none, text=black},
every label/.append style = {name=LN, anchor=south,     % <---
                font=\bfseries, text=black, 
                text width=10em, align=flush center,   % <---
                yshift=1ex},                           % <---
  FIT/.style = {draw=gray, fill=gray!30, rounded corners, 
                inner sep=1ex,
                fit=#1, node contents={}},
neuron/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                nodes={draw=pink, rounded corners, fill=gray!50, 
                       text height=2ex, minimum width=2em, 
                       inner sep=1mm,
                       text=#1},
                row sep=2mm,
                outer sep=0mm},
       }
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm and 1mm                            % <---
                       ]
%%%

\matrix (N2) [neuron=white,
             ]             % <---
{
|[label=Title]| a  \\
b    \\
d   \\
c     \\
};
%%%%
\matrix (N5) [neuron=white, right=-2.5cm of N2.east]
{
|[label= Title]| a      \\        % <--- longer label
b        \\
d   \\
c          \\
};
          
   % <---
\scoped[on background layer]
   \node (f4) [FIT={(N2-1-1) (N5-4-1)},draw=gray, fill=gray!30,rounded corners, inner xsep=20pt,inner ysep=1.5ex]{}; 
   
\scoped[on background layer]\node (f3) [FIT=(N5-1-1) (N5-4-1)]; 
\scoped[on background layer]\node (f2) [FIT=(N2-1-1) (N2-4-1)];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I updated my question to reflect more clearly, the node in the back spanning the two matrix and slightly bigger then what ` fit ` provides, thats why I used `shift ` but it doesnt work

Comment: @user0193 I update the answer, see if it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks,  accepted it. So you have used `right=-2.5cm of` to bring these matrix closer and `inner xsep=20pt,inner ysep=1.5ex` for expanding the outer box right?

Comment: @user0193 Right.